# Using RegexpVirtualURIMapping to map to static directories in Magnolia

Tags: java, spring, magnolia

I'd like to setup magnolia so that all requests to a directory will redirect to static resources. For example: if a URL matches `/campaign/(.*)` it will forward to `/static/campaign/` without redirecting.

```
/                        => [no change]
/campaign/               => /static/campaign/index.html
/campaign/styles/all.css => /static/campaign/styles/all.css
```

In the JCR, I've set `/modules/pages/virtualURIMapping` to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sv:node sv:name="virtualURIMapping" xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
    <sv:value>mgnl:content</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:node sv:name="default">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>mgnl:contentNode</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>c68cde34-eaaf-480d-b1fa-7ea98aa772b0</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="class" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.RegexpVirtualURIMapping</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="fromURI" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>/campaign/([0-9A-Z]*)</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="toURI" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>forward:/static/campaign/$1</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
  </sv:node>
</sv:node>
```

I've rebooted the server and I'm receiving the following exception:

```
ERROR info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter  - RepositoryException while reading Resource [/static]
javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: /static
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the forward to /static goes into the rendering filter. You need to exclude it by adding a bypass for /static/*

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want Magnolia to ignore, needs to be bypassed in either whole filter chain (if you want to ignore also authentication) or at least in `cms` subchain of filters.
To make Magnolia ignore some URIs, you need to configure bypass as mentioned already in other answer.

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating the following rewrite filter instead of adding to the JCR:

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>campaign</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.britishgas.contenthub.filters.CampaignRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>campaign</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/campaign/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

`Rewrite Filter`:

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CampaignRewriteFilter implements Filter {

    private RequestDispatcher defaultRequestDispatcher;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.defaultRequestDispatcher = filterConfig.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("default");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String uri = req.getRequestURI().replaceFirst("/campaign/", "/static/campaign/");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(uri);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```